# How to access filepath in aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

Here i have declared string variable on the top of the page like below

```
public string path; 
             protected void ViewFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
                        {
                 path = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
                            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"page_index_script","openPDF();",true);
                }
```

And I want to access this variable in aspx page inside script tag like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function openPDF() {
                    var strMessage ='<%= path%>';
                    var filepath = 'http://localhost:2878/your project name/' + strMessage;
                window.open(filepath , 'PDF');
                return true;
            }
        </script>
```

But the variable which holds the file path do not including the '/' as it treat filepath as a string
 and elinimate the '/' from that path. But i need not to elinimate that .how could it be possible?
Suppose filepath is like "file/Admin/PMS"
But it gives me on alerting the strMessage ,filepath as "fileAdminPMS"

Comment: What do you mean it eliminates the forward slashes? What does `alert(a);` give you? Please paste the exact text. Also, it's a good idea to give your variables descriptives names, as `p` and 'a` are not clear at all on what they are intended for.

Comment: alert(a) gives filepath as a string but it remove all the '/' forward slashes from that filepath ...As Suppose filepath is like D://file/TMS/    ....but it alerts as D:fileTMS

Comment: I have updated it...as i need to open file in a new window tab but filepath is not as it should be